# Google YouTube API v3 :: Server-to-Server Upload Service

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

Our project lets users upload videos to OUR public youtube channel when they are signed into our session. We do not want to require additional OAuth2 verification, and instead follow the follow of Google API v2.

My code (php) and error are below, but my general question is: **can my server make the insert-video POST using my API key/secrets without requiring the user to authenticate.**

This question - [Google Calendar API v3 hardcoded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257678/google-calendar-api-v3-hardcoded-credentials) - is very similar. Howevr if CURLing Google for the access_token is the only answer, i'll be disappointed. Thanks regardless.

**Google API V3 Settings:**

```
Client ID:  xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:  xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret:  xxxx
Redirect URIs:  http://fbtabs.imagendigital.co/unilever/sedal/surprise/galeria
JavaScript origins: https://fbtabs.imagendigital.co
API key:    
AIzaSyBgS-jMJQUPIiAyX20xC-encFWTPsR7qxQ
Referers:   
Any referer allowed
Activated on:   Jul 4, 2013 1:21 PM
Activated by:    xxxx@gmail.com – you
```

**Code:**

```
<?php
require_once BASE_CD . 'app/src/Idframework/Tools.php';
require_once BASE_CD . 'app/vendor/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once BASE_CD . 'app/vendor/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
$client->setClientId('xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://fbtabs.imagendigital.co/unilever/sedal/surprise/galeria');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx');
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
$status = new Google_VideoStatus();
$video = new Google_Video();

if (isset($_POST['tip_desc'])) $snippet->setDescription($_POST['tip_desc']);
    $snippet->setTitle($_POST['tip_name']);
    $snippet->setTags(array("sedal","hair","pello","cabello"));
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $filename = $_FILES['videoInp']['tmp_name'];
    $mime = \Idframework\Tools::get_mime($filename);

    try {
        $part = "status";
        $obj = $youtube->videos->insert($part, $video,
                                         array("data"=>file_get_contents($filename), 
                                        "mimeType" => $mime));
    } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
        print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage(). " <br>";
        print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: content-type in C:\DATA\IDInteractive\SedalSurprise\app\vendor\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_MediaFileUpload.php on line 99
Caught Google service Exception 401 message is Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=player&uploadType=multipart&key=AIzaSyBgS-jMJQUPIiAyX20xC-encFWTPsR7qxQ: (401) Login Required 
Stack trace is #0 C:\DATA\IDInteractive\SedalSurprise\app\vendor\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1 C:\DATA\IDInteractive\SedalSurprise\app\vendor\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2 C:\DATA\IDInteractive\SedalSurprise\app\vendor\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_YouTubeService.php(789): Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #3 C:\DATA\IDInteractive\SedalSurprise\youtuber.php(56): Google_VideosServiceResource->insert('player', Object(Google_Video), Array) #4 {main}
```

Comment: I solved it and my answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609138/how-to-insert-video-youtube-api-v3-through-service-account-with-ruby/27620954#27620954
Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, letting arbitrary users upload videos into a "master" YouTube channel is not recommended, for the reasons outlined in [this blog post](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.fr/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community_15.html).

That being said, if you're determined to do it, then you need to include an access token associated with your channel in each upload request. The appropriate way to get a fresh access token (they expire after an hour) is to take a refresh token that you've previously generated and stored somewhere and make an HTTP request to the appropriate URL to get back an access token, as explained in the [OAuth 2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). There's no way around that—I'm not sure whether there's a native method in the Google APIs PHP client library that will automate the process for you, but that's what needs to happen under the hood.

The information in [Google Calendar API v3 hardcoded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257678/google-calendar-api-v3-hardcoded-credentials) does seem relevant.