# How to post event to particular google calendar using feed URL

Tags: ios, events, post, google-calendar-api, feed

I am trying to post an event to a particular google calendar.
I am using the following URL to post the event:
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CALENDAR-ID/private/full

Using this I get this error:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Authorization required</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>Authorization required</H1>
    <H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
```

I understand that I need to request authorization to post on the calendar but I would like to post the event in my own calendar.

My questions:
1 - Do I need to use OAuth to post an event in my own calendar ?
2 - If not, is there any special URL (like magic-cookie) to use with a read-write access ?
3 - I have a Google API Key but I don't know if I can use it in this case and how it should be used ?

I am trying to post the event from an iOS application using NSURLConnection. Here is the details:

> {
>     "data": {
>       "title": "Tennis with Beth",
>       "details": "Meet for a quick lesson.",
>       "transparency": "opaque",
>       "status": "pending",
>       "location": "Rolling Lawn Courts",
>       "when": [
>         {
>           "start": "2013-08-07T15:00:00.000Z",
>           "end": "2013-08-07T17:00:00.000Z"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }

Headers:

> Content-type: application/json

Thank you for your help, I know there is a lot of similar question over internet but everything I try doesn't work and I don't understand the OAuth things in documentation (as I never used OAuth). Also I can;t find in google documentation the case when you want your users to post in a particular calendar.

Comment: I believe the doc you're looking for is https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#AuthInstalledOAuth .  Yes you need to use OAuth.

Comment: I thought OAuth was the method to get user's access, I don't see where it is written that I can request my own access, like a personal token ...

Comment: i need this to implement in my swift project could u help me with google calendar @foOg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another post on StackOverflow which deals exactly with what I was looking for. The post explain the method using PHP but the process is still the same for iOS.

[Google Calendar API v3 hardcoded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257678/google-calendar-api-v3-hardcoded-credentials)